# TableView didSelect and didDeselect issue

Tags: swift, objective-c, uitableview

When I click on didSelect event gets fired first time, but when I click on same row second time neither didDeselect event gets called nor didSelect. Any idea ?

Comment: Add some code for your tableview set up, your `didSelect`, `cellForRow atIndexpath`, didDeselct` - it might give us some clues as to what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug your code, first set break point or print in `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt`calling.  After that, when you run the app, you can use `Debug view Hierarchy` in xcode tool to detect which item doesn't allow to select the cell. Maybe your table is [image]reloaded and your cell is changed item position.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing to YES was causing the issue.